# jquery: how to trigger click.ui-foo event

Tags: jquery, events

jquery: how to trigger click.ui-foo event?

```
<div class="ui-foo"> </div>
<div id="foo-trigger"> </div>

$("#foo-trigger").on("click.ui-foo", function() { alert("clicked"); });
```

How is the event triggered? click the div "foo-trigger", nothing happened.
Why not just use the event "click"? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

**Event names and namespaces**

*Any event names can be used for the events argument. jQuery will pass through the browser's standard JavaScript event types, calling the handler function when the browser generates events due to user actions such as click. In addition, the .trigger() method can trigger both standard browser event names and custom event names to call attached handlers. Event names should only contain alphanumerics, underscore, and colon characters.*

Source: https://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names

```
<button id="foo-trigger">Click me!</button>

<button class="ui-foo">Trigger "Click me!"</button>

$("#foo-trigger").on("click.someNamespace", function (event) {
    alert(event.namespace);
});

$(".ui-foo").click(function (event) {
    $("#foo-trigger").trigger("click.someNamespace");

    // eventually remove element event by namespace
    // $("#foo-trigger").off("click.someNamespace");
});
```

Comment: triggering "click.someNamespace" will trigger javascript click event?  will mouse click trigger "click.someNamespace" event? thanks.